# MDX Children of Several Members

Tags: function, union, mdx, member, children

The children functions returns the set of the member.
But I need the children of several members.

The problem is, that I can't use Union to make it work like that:

```
Union([Geography].[Geography].[USA].children,[Geography].[Geography].[Canada].children)
```

I don't know how many member it will be... So I actually would need all children of a set of members.

like:

```
([Geography].[Geography].[USA],[Geography].[Geography].[Canada],[Geography].[Geography].[GB]).children
```

Is there a function like that?

---

I couldn't answer my question and so I just edit it. With the help of DHN's answer and some brain work I found a solution I could use:

```
Except(DRILLDOWNLEVEL( {[Geography].[Geography].[USA],[Geography].[Geography].[Canada]},,0 ),
{[Geography].[Geography].[USA],[Geography].[Geography].[Canada]})
```

That does work for me.
Explanation: I drilldown the elements the tool provides me, which returns children plus parents and then I use DHN's idea and except the parents so clean the list up a bit.

Hopefully it is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually, you could use a [Crossjoin](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144816.aspx) to get the set you want.

Something like

```
[Geography].[Geography].[USA] * [Geography].[Geography].[Canada] * [Geography].[Geography].[GB]
```

But this is only a proper solution, if you have only a few different search criteria.

Alternatively, you could use [Except](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144900.aspx) to remove those criteria you're not interested in. E.g.

```
Except([Geography].[Geography].children, [Geography].[Geography].[Germany])
```

This would give you the whole content of the `[Geography]` dimension, except the one of `[Germany]`.

Hope this helps a bit.

**Edit after comment of TO**

Ok, this wasn't part of your question, but I think what you need is the `MemberToStr()` function. Please find the doc [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144775.aspx).

I think something like this should do the trick.

```
with   member [Measures].[Cities]
as     membertostr([Geography].[Geography].members.children)
select [Measures].[Cities] on 0
from   [WhatEverYourCubeNameIs]    
where  (
    [Geography].[Geography].[USA],
    [Geography].[Geography].[Canada]
)
```

Please note that this query is totally untested. I also may have lost some of my skills, because it's been a while, since I used [mdx](/questions/tagged/mdx). You will also have to create the query dynamically, since the selection seems to be user dependant. But I'm sure that you're aware of it. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But the problem is, that the set of members is generated dynamically. Which means that someone multiselects the countries in a dropdown. So if someone selects USA and Canada (and children are cities) - it should return a set like "Seattle, LA, Vancouver, ..."

Comment: Please find my extended answer. The next time you should be more clear with your question. It was not obivious, what you're trying to achieve. Nevertheless, hope it helps. ;)

Comment: Thanks mate - I also edited my question. Guess we both found a solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Descendants` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146075.aspx) (the fourth form of the description linked uses a set as its first argument. Thus,

```
Descendants( { 
             [Geography].[Geography].[USA],
             [Geography].[Geography].[Canada],
             [Geography].[Geography].[GB]
             },
             1,
             SELF
           )
```

should deliver exactly what you want.